# ReturnUrl QueryString always is null in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a action method for login with get method:

```
public virtual ActionResult LogIn()
{
    return View();
}
```

and an action method for Post method which post in Ajax call with Ajax.BeginForm(),like:

```
[HttpPost]
[AjaxOnly]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual ActionResult LogIn(LogInViewModel loginInfo, string returnUrl)
{
   ...
}
```

But returnUrl always is null!!!

i use MVC 4.

what is cause of this problem?

Comment: What are you sending back to the server? It looks like returnUrl is not coming back.

Comment: when user request actions which tagged with Authorize attribute and user not Authenticated Then user redirect to LogIn action and returnUrl add to Query String.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to send the returnUrl back to the server. For example your login form should take returnUrl as a parameter:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
    ....
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
}
```

which was previously saved at the server side in your login action, invoked as a result of usage AuthorizeAttribute with ReturnUrl passed in the query string:

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: very thank you,i edited question for completion your answer,please see that.

Comment: i accepted your answer and complete your answer in my question ;)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what your view looks like, but if you have something like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
}
```

...then `returnUrl` should have a populated value, that's if it came from another url.

In my scenario it was always null, and I am assuming it was probably the same way that you did it. I had it like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
{
}
```

All that I did was change it to look like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", new { returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
{
}
```

`returnUrl` now has a value that I can work with.

Answer (score 0):

in continue for Completion good answer of @Jaroslaw Waliszko,cause of this problem is:

because we use a ajax request for submit form,unobtrusive ajax use

```
$("form").serialize();
```

for this form and at this case(use ajax) ReturnUrl(and any other parameter) not send to server and only form input element send to server,So MVC Auto ModelBinding not bind ReturnUrl and we must use @Jaroslaw Waliszko solution at this state.

[serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

> Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.